# bp_member_profile_data - Can't get result to show

Tags: php, buddypress

I am trying to add a specific field used in BuddyPress that show what games people play. I want it to show up on the member directory list just under their name. But no matter what i do it won't show up.

I have added it here:

```
         * Fires inside the display of a directory member item.
         *
         * @since 1.1.0
         */
        do_action( 'bp_directory_members_item' ); ?>
        <?php
         /***
          * If you want to show specific profile fields here you can,
          * but it'll add an extra query for each member in the loop
          * (only one regardless of the number of fields you show):
          *
          * bp_member_profile_data( 'field=the field name' );
          */

       bp_member_profile_data( 'field=games' );
        ?>
```

What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try This `<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'games', bp_get_member_user_id() ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the function again. Don't forget to use exactly the same title with uppercase if it's the case :

```
bp_member_profile_data( 'field=games' ); echo '<br>';
bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Affiliation' );
```